# Invalid Token PaswordReset ASP.Net with same code in mail and controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

**This code sends the token in the email**

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
        if (user == null || !(await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id)))
        {
            return View("ForgotPasswordConfirmation");
        }

        var code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
        var client = new SmtpClient(send is OK)

        { Credentials = new NetworkCredential("somemail", "pass"),EnableSsl = true };

        var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
        var message = new MailMessage

        { From = new MailAddress("somemail"),Subject = "<h2>Reset pass<h2>", Body = " reset pass here : " + callbackUrl, IsBodyHtml = true };

        message.To.Add(model.Email);
        client.Send(message);

        return RedirectToAction("ForgotPasswordConfirmation", "Account");
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

**This catch it and send to View (I tried it two ways)**

```
[HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult ResetPassword(string code)
        {
            //return code == null ? View("Error") : View(new ResetPasswordViewModel { Code = code });
            return code == null ? View("Error") : View();
        }
```

**And here is result "Invalid Token."**

```
[HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> ResetPassword(ResetPasswordViewModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model);
            }
            var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
            if (user == null)
            {
                // Don't reveal that the user does not exist
                return RedirectToAction("ResetPasswordConfirmation", "Account");
            }

            var result = await UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user.Id, model.Code, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("ResetPasswordConfirmation", "Account");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
            return View();
        }
```

**But why ? The code is the same when sending ( callbackUrl ) upon takeover (string code) and at the end ( model.Code ).**

So I am really confused. Here is a lot of solution but there is the only problem with the null code or different code. I have good code and still error Invalid Token.

Please have someone any ideas?

Comment: Sorry for my english. Many Thanks for your edit :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solution. It is my foulth.

I made Token here

`var code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);`

and check here

```
var result = await UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user.Id, model.Code, model.Password);
```

So I generate Email token and check Password Token.

When I change it, everything works !

Comment: I hope it helps somebody. Next time I must better check my code.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Code)
```

in your reset form?? otherwise your code will not get to the last ActionResult